# What run-time configuration parameters are used for concurrent index creation

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.3

Suppose I were to run the following. The first line shows the server's default maintenance_work_mem value.

```
mhildreth=# show maintenance_work_mem;
 maintenance_work_mem
----------------------
 16MB
(1 row)

mhildreth=# set maintenance_work_mem = '256MB';
SET

mhildreth=# CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ON my_table(columns);

mhildreth=# set maintenance_work_mem = DEFAULT;
SET
```

What would be used for maintenance_work_mem of the index creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the `maintenance_work_mem` you have set of 256MB should be seen by the subsequent `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` command, because you have changed this GUC inside your session.

In fact, the docs [suggest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/populate.html#POPULATE-WORK-MEM) bumping up `maintenance_work_mem` (as you showed) for just such a purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was under the mistaken impression that CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY would actually kick off some background job to do the index creation, and was worried that the background job wouldn't have the changes to the GUC. Since this assumption is false, it does make sense that the new config would hold.